# Controller method not updating(same result every time)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have following method in my mvc controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult UserProfile(String username)
{
     var user = db.Users.Find(username);

     return View(user);
}
```

This function returns View with user profile. But result of this is the same, regardless of changes in database.

When I debug it seems like `db` is not changing at all, while in other controllers everything works just fine.

EDIT:
Place when I make changes

```
public ActionResult ExecuteRetreive(String username, String ISBN)
    {
        if (IsValid(username))
        {
            var resBook = db.Books.Find(ISBN);
            var resUser = db.Users.Find(username);
            var resRentedBooks = (from rb in db.RentedBooks
                                  join b in db.Books on rb.ISBN equals b.ISBN
                                  where b.ISBN == ISBN
                                  where rb.Login == username
                                  where rb.Returned == null
                                  select rb).FirstOrDefault();
            if (resRentedBooks == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Fail", "FailSuccess",
                                        new { error = "" });
            }

            resRentedBooks.Returned = DateTime.Now;

            resBook.IsRented = false;
            resUser.RentedBooks--;

            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Success", "FailSuccess");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Fail", "FailSuccess",
                new { error = "Niepoprawna nazwa użytkownika" });
        }
    }
```

Im new to this so dont laugh at my code :P When I display `resUser.RentedBooks--;` it is the same every time.

Comment: Are you sure you're calling `SaveChanges()` on your `DatabaseContext` object?

Comment: What do you expect to be changed in the database? You're not changing anything here. Post the code where you make the change.

Comment: yes, but mby it will help when I say that this context is static in every controller

Comment: Contexts are made to be used once and disposed afterwards. Don't make them static at all, just use `using(db) { }` every time you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a follow up to what @JeroenVannevel said in the comments, another problem that you might be having because you're using a static context (and one that I've had to deal with in the past) is that once a specific `DbContext` has loaded an entity (or a set of entities, in my case) it won't tend to refresh just because some outside changes were made in the database. It loads those entities into `Local` and just refers to those automatically if you query for it.

The solution, then, is to always put your `DbContext` calls wrapped up in a `using` block, since `DbContext` implements `IDisposable`.

One word of caution with this approach, since you're using MVC: If you are using lazy loading, and you know that your View will need some information from a child object (or to list the names of a collection of child objects), you will absolutely need to hydrate those child entities *before* you get out of the `using` block, or you will find yourself getting exceptions saying that your context has been disposed.

Comment: That helped. I was using `using` earlier, but it was rly uncomfortable, so I changed db to static.